# How to convert F and t-values to standardized Z scores?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, meta-analysis, standardization

What is a good reference for converting F, t, and eta-squared values into standardized z scores for a meta-analysis? A psychology oriented textbook/reference would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't the p-value translate directly to a Z score?  And anyone quoting one of these statistics surely is giving a p-value with it.  If it's only an approximate one (e.g., "<0.05"), then compute the p-value yourself from the statistic and its degrees of freedom and go from there.

Comment: What software are you using that requires a z-score? Meta-analysis software typically (in my experience) wants an effect size and a standard error, or a means to calculate that.

Answer (score 0):

For independent $t$ assuming you have the means you can back-calculate the standard error of that mean difference and hence eventually the standardised mean difference.

If F is for an ANOVA then there are many possible mean differences so that is undefined. If it is for two groups then $t = \sqrt{F}$

No idea how to do $\eta^2$ but similar considerations apply as for $F$ I would have thought.